# Exception ocurred when processing wsgi script

Tags: django, apache, centos7, mod-wsgi

I have a Django 2.0.5 app and a Centos7 server with httpd. I would like to deploy the app with httpd but I'm receiving an error when apache is processing the wsgi script

```
mod_wsgi (pid=17647): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/quiq/apache.conf/web.wsgi'.
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
mod_wsgi (pid=17648): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/quiq/apache.conf/web.wsgi'.
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

WSGI script

```
import os, sys
#import django.core.handlers.wsgi

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/quiq/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Rest_SL_Algorithm.settings'

# avoid UnicodeEncodeError
os.environ.setdefault("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8")
os.environ.setdefault("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

##activamos nuestro virtualenv
activate_this = '/var/www/html/quiq/quiqenv/bin/activate_this.py'
#execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
#exec(open('/var/www/html/quiq/quiqenv/bin/activate_this.py').read())
exec(compile(open(activate_this, "rb").read(), activate_this, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this))
#_application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
_application = get_wsgi_application()


def application(environ, start_response):
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] + environ['PATH_INFO']
    if environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] == 'https':
        environ['HTTPS'] = 'on'
        return _application(environ, start_response)
```

and my httpd conf for the project

```
<virtualhost *:80>

    ServerName algorithm

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/quiq

    <Directory /var/www/html/quiq>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess dev.algorithm.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}

    WSGIProcessGroup dev.algorithm.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/quiq/apache.conf/web.wsgi

    Alias /media /var/www/html/quiq/media/
    <Directory /var/www/html/quiq/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/quiq/staticfiles/
    <Directory /var/www/html/quiq/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/pyerror.log
    CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/pyaccess.log combined

</virtualhost>
```

I had to make several work arounds when installing on centos such installing `centos-release-scl` and `rh-python`

The extrange thing is when I execute the  same commands on the python console it tells me that the django module could not be found.

Any help on what should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're only listening on port 80, which is http, but your wsgi file returns nothing if the scheme is not https. You shouldn't do that check in wsgi anyway; do it in the apache config.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks @DanielRoseman